# Why does MANIFEST.MF file contain information about the other files that are packaged in the archive?

Tags: java, manifest.mf

I was still confused about why would MANIFEST.MF file contain info about other files that are packaged in the archive. I read this [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/defman.html) on manifest and they have not explained why it contain info about other files.

Ta

Answer (score 1):

The quote is

> The manifest can also contain information about the other files that are packaged in the archive. Exactly what file information should be recorded in the manifest depends on how you intend to use the JAR file. The default manifest makes no assumptions about what information it should record about other files.

The point being it doesn't have to but it might.

For example, OSGi stores information about package versions and dependencies.

Comment: So what your saying is that the reason it contain info about other files that are packaged in the archive, so that frameworks like OSGi would use it in some scenarios. right?

Comment: yes.  Normally properties files are used, but using a MANIFEST file makes sense for OGSi as it is a known location where it can store information for all packages.